# The first page of the chapter on the right-hand side of two page view mode

Tags: chapters

I write a thesis using Latex and I have an issue with the page where starts all chapters. Let's note some technical
details:

1. `\documentclass[..., twoside=true]{scrbook}`
2. I used  `\include`  command for every chapter.

I need that every chapter to start on the right-hand side of a pair of two pages (imagine when the book is open). I tried
to include a black page but it doesn't work. Some instances with my attempts were:

1. `\include{black_page}` , where blank_page contains the code:  `\thispagestyle{empty}\phantom{~}\vfill` .
2. Insert the code  `\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}\mbox{}`  at the beginning of the chapter.
3. Insert  `\clearpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}`  at the beginning of the chapter to insert an even-numbered page before the beginning of the chapter.
4. I used the open command from the Koma-script documentation, but now the all the chapters starts with even page number and I need to be an odd page number.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: by default scrbook opens chapters on right, odd numbered pages. If this doesn't happens for you your code is changing this.

Comment: The `\include` command always starts a new page. Have you tried `\input` instead?